# I am getting error in my consumer microservice, i am trying to consume json object in kafka in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, microservices

I have created this notification microservice. From which i want to consume object with type UserDTO

```
UserDTO.java

package com.example.notificationservice.model;

public class UserDTO {
    private String userId;
    private String userName;
    private String email;
       
   // getters and setters     
}


// KafkaMessageListener.java

package com.example.notificationservice.consumer;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.notificationservice.model.UserDTO;

@Service
public class KafkaMessageListener {

    org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaMessageListener.class);
    
    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic-example16", groupId = "group12")
    public void consume(UserDTO user) {
        log.info("consumer consume {}", user);
    }
}


application.properties

spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=group12
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.key.delegate=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.default.type=com.example.notificationservice.model.UserDTO
```

And this is My Code for Producer Side

```
// ProducerController.java

package com.kafkaProducer.producer;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.kafkaProducer.UserDTO;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/kafka")
public class ProducerController {

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, UserDTO> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public ProducerController(KafkaTemplate<String, UserDTO> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    @PostMapping("/send")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendMessage(@RequestBody UserDTO user) {
        
        kafkaTemplate.send("topic-example16", user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok("User data sent to Kafka.");
    }
}

application.properties

spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092

spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

My Producer side is able to write data in the topic, i have checked through offset explorer.
I am getting when running consumer side(Notification microservice).
This are the errors:

```
ERROR[0;39m [35m30932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; **nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: **Failed to construct kafka consumer****
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:357) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:156) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:124) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.7.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.7.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.7.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.7.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.7.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.7.16-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.notificationservice.NotificationServiceApplication.main(NotificationServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
**Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer**
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:823) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:664) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createRawConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:483) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:451) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumerWithAdjustedProperties(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:427) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:394) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:371) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:778) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:352) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:461) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:226) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:461) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:363) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:308) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No delegate deserializer configured**
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer.configure(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.java:138) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.11.jar:2.8.11]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:716) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

I have checked through offset explorer, my topic is there with data. [image: Offset Explorer Screenshot]

And this is the screenshot of postman, In which i am running producer rest controller

[image: Postman Screenshot]

I have tried searching errors in google, but i am not able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Now, my problem is solved.

In application.properties, consumer value deserializer line was wrong. It should be

spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer:org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer